# How to pick some items in list of lists and check if it exists in list of tuples

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement, tuples

Assume I have list of tuples `edges = [(0,1),(0,3),(0,4),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4)]` and list of lists
`vertices = [[1,4,2,3,0],[3,0,1,2,4],[2,3,0,1,4],[1,3,2,1,4],[0,3,2,4,1]]`. Then I want to check if first and last element of each list in vertices exists in edges then do some stuff.

For example in the first list of vertices which is `[1,4,2,3,0]`, first and last items which are `1` and `0` exits in edges `(0,1)` (it could be both (0,1) and (1,0)) then do some stuff and same for all list of vertices. I am not sure how to continue the code below.

```
edges = [(0,1),(0,3),(0,4),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4)]
vertices = [[1,4,2,3,0],[3,0,1,2,4],[2,3,0,1,4],[1,3,2,1,4],[0,3,2,4,1]]

for i in range(len(vertices)):
    if vertices[i][0] and vertices[i][-1] in edges:
        do stuff...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compare your values with tuples then you should probably make them into tuples:

```
for idx, i in enumerate(vertices):
    t = tuple((i[0], i[-1]))
    if t in edges:
        print(f'Item {idx} matches edge {t}.')
    elif t[::-1] in edges:
        print(f'Item {idx} matches edge {t[::-1]}.')

Out:
Item 0 matches edge (0, 1).
Item 2 matches edge (2, 4).
Item 3 matches edge (1, 4).
Item 4 matches edge (0, 1).
```

**EDIT:** A more generic version that gives you indices of matching items both for vertices and edges.

```
for idx, i in enumerate(vertices):
    t = tuple((i[0], i[-1]))
    for j, k in enumerate(edges):
        if t == k:
            print(f'Vertex {idx} matches edge {t} at index {j}.')
        elif t[::-1] == k:
            print(f'Vertex {idx} matches edge {t[::-1]} at index {j}.') 

Out:
Vertex 0 matches edge (0, 1) at index 0.
Vertex 2 matches edge (2, 4) at index 7.
Vertex 3 matches edge (1, 4) at index 5.
Vertex 4 matches edge (0, 1) at index 0.
```

Comment: Yes, as Nick said it should include both (1,0) and (0,1).

Comment: @Aras, updated the answer so now it includes both.

Comment: (0,1) could have any index. Your code is just working for this specific case. Can you generalize it?

Comment: @Aras, updated. I hope that's what you needed.